# Backbone.js click not firing

Tags: backbone.js, click, backbone-views, backbone-events

I started helping someone on a project and one of the click button doesn't work. However, on the staging server, the same identical code for the click works. Any ideas what is causing this? I am new to backbone.js and I am not sure how the same exact code can act differently on two server. I have use code comparing tools to check all the files for differences that might cause this and havn't found anything. Please see below for my code. Thanks for the help!

View.js

```
Views.Pin = Backbone.View.extend({

events: {
    "click .gobackback": 'changeHistory'}

changeHistory: function(e) {
    Backbone.history.navigate('/', {
        trigger: true
    }); /* strip url definition available in actions.js */
    changeTitle("Home | Wazaap");
}
};
```

html

```
<span class="gobackback">&larr; GO BACK</span>
```

Comment: Is the problem that the changeHistory method isn't firing or is it that the history.navigate isn't working?

Comment: It seems like it's the method that is not firing.

Comment: Is the el for the view properly hooked up to the element you've defined handlers on?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML

Instead of

```
<span class="gobackback">&larr; GO BACK</span>
```

Try

```
<script type="text/template" id="goback_template">
          <span class="gobackback">&larr; GO BACK</span>
</script>
```

and in view add this

```
render: function() {
        var template = _.template($('#goback_template').html());
 }
```